# Is it possible to convert audio file with some music notes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio

I have a music file with a particular tone(music.mp4). I want to convert existing sound file (speech.mp4) into the tone which is specified in music.mp4. Its like converting a speech into some particular tone. I do not want to play both files simultaneously. I want to convert source file with help of some music file. So, output file will be converted file.

Is it possible? I searched for Audio Unit Hosting and Multimedia guide. But do not get any clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not specific to iOS but to sound processing in general. My guess is that the answer is you need to learn how to program code that does sound processing.

Comment: Apparently the question is very vague, I couldn't understand "this tone". What are you referring by saying "this tone"? it is better to rephrase the current question thanks.

Comment: @dbrajkovic Actually I want to do it with iOS APIs. So i put the question here. Is it possible through iOS APIs?

Comment: @dontCheckMyBlog Edited the post. Is it fine now?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it sounds (no pun intended) like it would be possible with the iOS. You just need to find someone who knows how to program that specific functionality. I do not know why you would think to find the answer in the Apple Docs. I want to know if it's possible to program music that plays backwards. I want to know if I can program a sound that converts my words into something my dog understands. I can't imagine the documentation could possibly cover everything everyone ever wants to program an iPhone to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are no iOS public APIs for frequency analysis of audio files.  You would have to write your own DSP code for that.  The AVFoundation and Accelerate frameworks have some audio file conversion and math functions that may help, but that is only a small portion of the code needed.